# Обрезать строку от и до определенного символа, PHP

Tags: php

Есть строка типа `$str = +124+567+68+8362;` 
Нужно получить все эти числа от + и до + в массив:

> [124] ... [8362]

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: explode('+', $str) даже стыдно писать ответ

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_filter(explode('+',$str));
```

Фильтр на случай если первый символ строки тоже разделитель, в данном случаи "+".

Comment: `explode('+', ltrim($str, '+'));` - альтернатива

Comment: спасибо за помощь, работает